# How many non isomorphic groups of order 30 are there?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $|G|=30$.  I have prove that there is the only subgroup of order $15$, which I'll denote $H$. Now I do know how to classify the group.  After thinking, I made the following steps.

1) Possible order of subgroup $K$ of $G$ of order 2 are 1, 3, 5, 15.

Case 1. if $G$ contain only one element of order 2, then $G \cong Z_{30}$.

Now I cannot solve for the next steps.
Please give me any hints or any other method.

Comment: @Anindya, you really must make more efforts to write correctly your question, and not only from a grammatical point of view. For example, in (1), what does "possible subgroup...of order 2 are 1,3,5,15" mean?!

Comment: I would like to point you to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/569226/61691. That question has been marked as a duplicate of this one, but it is higher voted and it has the higher voted answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hints:

1) There is only one possible **abelian** group of order $\,30\,$

2) Any group $\,G\,$ of order 30 has a subgroup $\,H\,$ of order $\,15\,$, which is normal and abelian -- in fact, cyclic -- (why and why?), and thus $\,G\cong H\rtimes Q\,$ , for some subgroup $\,Q:=\langle\,q\,\rangle\,$ of order two.

Since $\,\operatorname{Aut}(H)\cong C_2\times C_4\,$ (why?) , there are at least four possible homomorphisms $\,Q\to\operatorname{Aut}(H)\,$ , all of them convolutions:  (i) mapping $\,q\,$ to the generator of the factor $\,C_2\,$ , (ii) to  $\,p^2\;,\;\;p=$ the generator of $\,C_4\,$ ,  and (iii) to the element $\,(q,p)\in C_2\times C_4\,$ (the trivial homomorphism gives the abelian group we already had before).

Check the above three non-trivial homomorphisms give three non-isomorphic groups of order $\;30\;$ .

Comment: Does $Q$ is normal?

Comment: Not in general, @AnindyaGhatak . In fact, it is normal iff $\,G\,$ is a *direct product*, and since both $\,H,Q\,$ are abelian we'd be back in case (1).

Comment: in (ii), mapping q to p won't give a homomorphism.

Comment: You will have to be way more explicit here, @azimut, as it's almost nine months since this stufff: what are $\;p,q\;$ ?

Comment: As you defined them in your answer. The problem is that the order of q is 2 and the order of p is 4. So there is no homomorphism mapping q to p.

Comment: Did you get the point? I'm asking because you have edited your answer, but the problem is still there. In particular, the last sentence doesn't make sense, since there are no two homomorphisms in (ii), but only one. You can compare to my answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/569260/61691 which I just gave to a duplicate.

Comment: No, I just changed that ridiculous little $\;3\;$ that was there for the correct $\;2\;$ . Lemme see if I can remember what was going on here...

Comment: Well, I think I see it now: it must be "...to $\;p^2\;$" instead of $\;p\;$ there. I shall edit after you check this as you seem to be mroe into it than I am.

Comment: Yes, exactly. $q \mapsto p^2$ works, but $q \mapsto p$ cannot work because of the order argument. So no two possible homomorphisms in (ii), but only one.

Comment: Yes, only one there, yet four in total with the trivial one, I guess...

Comment: Correct, the trivial homomorphism corresponds to the abelian group $\mathbb Z/30\mathbb Z$.

Comment: In fact this simplifies the argument there, as no-need to check the supposedly two homom.'s in (ii) give isomorphic groups...thanks.

Comment: Sorry for being nitpicking: There is still something missing to a complete answer to the question: Why are there no more than those 4 isomorphism types? (I did this in my answer by the argument that there are only 4 suitable elements in $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$.)

Comment: How you say you did it I also did it: aren't the given, corrected options to map $\;q\;$ *all* there is?

Comment: Of course the list of options you give is complete, but neither is this stated in your answer nor is the argument (based on the order) given. Instead, you write "there are at least four possible homomorphisms" which suggests that there might be more.

Comment: Indeed so, @azimut . If you check my different answers not many times I give a complete, definite answer. I leave stuff for the OP to fill up

Comment: @DonAntonio: I'm sorry. I didn't realize that you wrote "Hints:" in the first line.

Comment: I know it is very old, but how did you get the intuition of using automorphism groups? Is it standard procedure?

Comment: @RohanRajagopal Whenever we have a semidirect product as in my answer, there exisats a homomorphism from the right factor into the automorphism group of the left factor. This is the explanation why there's stuff about automorphism groups in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

There is a general description of groups with cyclic Sylow subgroups:

Marshall Hall, The Theory of Groups -  Theorem 9.4.3.

Comment: Here is a reference to this result at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-group#Groups_whose_Sylow_subgroups_are_cyclic).