# What is the intuition that this theorem should give?

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

I am reading the direct products and here is a theorem that I could't understand its serve well:

> A group of order 30 is ismorphic to one of
>
> $C_{30}, C_5\times D(3), C_3\times D(5)\qquad \qquad,$ or  $\qquad D(15)$

Which type of groups are $C_{30}, C_5, C_3 $?
And I also couldn't follow the reasoning in this example that the book gave after that theorem:

> The group with presentation
> $$ \big <x,y : x^{15}=1=y^2, yxy^{-1}=x^4 \big > $$
> is isomorphic to the direct product $C_3\times D(5)$

Comment: $C_n$ denotes the cyclic group of order $n$.

Comment: You should start from recalling that $D_n$ is not an abelian group if $n\geq 3$, then compare the multiplication tables of $C_3\times D_5$ and the group presented by such relations (this is a pretty inefficient approach, indeed, but it surely works).

Comment: You can find more detail atlas of finite group:http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/

Comment: Your first question answer is there:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569226/classification-of-groups-of-order-30