# Construction of groups with arbitrarily $n_p$ number of Sylow $p$-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $p^\alpha m$, and denote $\text{Syl}_p(G)$ to be the set of all Sylow $p$-subgroups. Define $n_p = |\text{Syl}_p(G)|$. Sylow's Third Theorem asserts that $n_p \equiv 1\text{ (mod $p$)}$, and $n_p \mid |G|$.

Now we fix $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. For any $n_p$ that satisfies the two conditions stated above, can we always construct a group $G$ of order $p^\alpha m$ such that $|\text{Syl}_p(G)| = n_p$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, there is no group of order $30$ with $6$ Sylow $5$-subgroups.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a paper/link to support this claim?

Comment: I expect groups of order 30 have been discussed before on this forum.

Comment: You're right. This is the link in case anyone else wants to have a reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569226/classification-of-groups-of-order-30

Comment: There is also a 1967 paper of Marshall Hall which studies the possible values of $n_p$. Example result: $22 \equiv 1 \mod{3}$, but there is no finite group $G$ with $22$ Sylow $3$-subgroups.