# If $|G|=30$ then $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $15$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

If $|G|=30$ then $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $15$

It's duplicate of [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569226/classification-of-groups-of-order-30) but I am posting it to verify my solution. I am not sure if it's correct.

---

From the $1$st theorem, we get that exist a subgroup order $3 $ and $5$

From the $3$rd we get that $n_3 \equiv 1 \bmod{3}$ and $n_3  \mid 10$ so $n_3 = 1$ therefore from the lemma that says every sylow-p group is normal iff $n_p=1$ we get $n_3$ is normal, same thing for $n_5$

Since it exists, a subgroup with order $3$, call it $H$ then because $3$ is prime $H$ is cyclic and abelian same for the subgroup with order $5$ call it $N$

Then I want to use  $K\cong H\times N$ where $K$ is the  normal subgroup of order $15$.

By using the theorem that requires $N,H$ to be normal subgroups $NH=K$ and $N\cap H=\{e\}$ (which is true because if $x\neq e \in N\cap H $ from Lagrange theorem we have a contradiction) I get  indeed that  $K\cong H\times N$ which is an abelian group of order $15$

**My questions: does this truly prove that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$?**

**Is this proof correct?**

Comment: If $n_3$ must be congruent to $1$ modulo $3$ and divide $10$, why cannot it be $10$? And $n_5$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $5$ and divides $6$, so presumably it could be $6$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ooh I misted that you are right. Can I somehow "save it" or my hole idea collapse there ?

Comment: @EricTowers that's the order, the symbol $| |$ translates to the order.

Comment: @EricTowers you are right, when I am posting its getting really late and I make mistakes like that because I am tired. i will fix it.

Comment: you can save it. If $n_5=6$ then since Sylow subs a cyclic of order 5, the number of elements of order 5 is $6*4=24$. Hence the number of elements of order $3$ is at most $30-25=5$. Hence the number of Sylow 3-subgroups is at most $3$. Then $n_3$ must be 1 as you proved. Hence there is one (normal) subgroup of order $3$, $S_3$. Take any Sylow $5$-subgroup $S_5$. Then $S_3S_5$ is a subgroup of order $15$. Similarly if $n_5=1$, then $S_5$ is normal and again $S_3S_5$ has order $15$.

Comment: @markvs now that i am looking it again, why do i need to show that $n_3=1$ and $n_5=1$, my main argument is that it exist groups with that order, and then i construct $K$ from them, is this wrong?

Comment: no you only need to show that **either** $n_3=1$ **or** $n_5=1$.

Comment: @markvs ok thanks for helping, I will study also tomorrow with a clear head.

Comment: The fact that the subgroup of order $15$ is normal is obvious because its index is $2$.