# Let $G$ be a group of order $120$ has a normal subgroup of order $2$ or index $2$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $120$ with no normal subgroup of order $5$. Then $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $2$ or index $2$.

**My attempt:** Let $n_5$ denote the number of Sylow $5$-subgroups of $G$. By Sylow's theorem, we obtain $n_5=6$ and $G$ acts on the set of Sylow $5$-subgroups by conjugation. Therefore there exists a homomorphism $\phi: G\to S_6$. We now consider two cases:

**Case 1: G is simple.** Then $\ker \phi = 1$ or $G$. If $\ker \phi=1$, then $G=S_6$ is not simple, a contradiction. If $\ker \phi=G$, then the action of $G$ on $X$ is trivial, which contradicts that the Sylow $5$-subgroups are not normal. So, this case cannot hold.

**Case 2: G is not simple.** Then $G$ has a proper non-trivial normal subgroup, say $H$.

---

How to proceed?

Comment: I'm not good at algebra, but I remember that $n_{5}\equiv 1 (5)$. So $n_{5}$ cannot be 5...

Comment: Misprint: $n_5=6$.

Comment: The kernel being trivial tells you the morphism is injective. But you cannot conclude the map is surjective. The image would have order $120$, but $S_6$ has order $720$. Your claim in the first case that if the kernel is trivial then $G$ is $S_6$ is false.

Comment: You have a map into $S_6$. If the image is not contained in $A_6$, then the intersection with $A_6$ will yield a subgroup of index $2$. If the image is contained in $A_6$, then find the transitive subgroups (not that many) and use the possible images to get the desired subgroups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me correct and finish the OP's attempt:

**Case 1:** $\phi$ is injective.
Since $A_6$ is simple, it cannot have a subgroup of index $3$ (otherwise there would be a non-trivial homomorphismus $A_6\to S_3$). Hence, $\phi(G)$ is not contained in $A_6$. Consequently, $S_6=A_6\phi(G)$ and $|\phi(G):\phi(G)\cap A_6|=|S_6:A_6|=2$. Since $G\cong\phi(G)$, we are done.

**Case 2:** $\phi$ is not injective. Since $G$ acts transitively on the set of Sylow $5$-subgroups, $|\phi(G)|$ is divisible by $6$. Therefore, $|\ker\phi|$ divides $20$. If $\ker\phi$ contains a Sylow $5$-subgroup $P$, then $P$ would be characteristic in $\ker\phi$ (by Sylow's theorem) and normal in $G$. This was excluded. Thus, $|\ker\phi|$ divides $4$. We may assume that $|\ker\phi|=4$. Then $|G/\ker\phi|=30$. It is easy to show that every group of order $30$ has a normal Sylow $5$-subgroup (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/569260/960602). Taking the preimage, we obtain a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $20$, which was already excluded.

There are probably shorter arguments.

*Addendum:* The statement is true without the hypothesis on the Sylow $5$-subgroups: **Every group of order 120 possesses a normal subgroup of order 2 or index 2.**

Comment: An alternative argument for the case $|\phi(G)|=30$: in that case an element of order $2$ in $\phi(G)$ would be fixed point free and hence would be an odd permutation, so $\phi(G) \not\le A_6$, giving a subgroup of index $2$ as in Case 1.

Comment: Alternatively, if the Sylow $5$-subgroup is of $\phi(G)$ is not normal, then $\phi(G)$ has $24$ elements of order $5$ and so at most $5$ elements of order $3$. Thus, the subgroup of order $3$ must be normal. This gives a normal subgroup of order $15$. Pulling back, we get an index $2$ subgroup.

Comment: @Guest yes, indeed this is already a contradiction without pulling back, since a subgroup of order 15 has a normal Sylow 5-subgroup, which will be normal in the group of order 30. By the way, I realized that the whole statement remains true without the hypothesis on the number of Sylow 5-subgroups.