# Help Understanding Explicit Automorphism Formulas for Semi-Direct Products

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, semidirect-product

I'm currently working through some material on semi-direct products, and I'm totally confused by some of the explicit examples given for semi-direct products, namely how one determines the automorphisms.

For example, In classifying groups of order $30$, done [here specifically](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569226/classification-of-groups-of-order-30), the answer makes sense in that there are four possible automorphisms given by $\varphi(1) \in \{(0,0), (1,0), (0,2), (1,2)\}$, but what are these automorphisms?

For $\varphi(1) = (0,0)$, I get this is a trivial map corresponding to simply the direct product.

What about $\varphi(1) = (1,0)$, what's an explicit formula for this automorphism?  Semi-direct products of this form arise from the action of conjugation of the right factor $K$ on the left factor $H$ (for a semi direct product $H \rtimes_{\varphi} K$).  In this case, we have a Sylow $2$ subgroup $P_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, and a group $N \cong \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ of order $15$.

The theory states that if $\varphi: K \longrightarrow \text{Aut}(H)$, then $\varphi(k)[(h)] = khk^{-1}$.  So if $\varphi(1) = (1,0)$, then wouldn't we simply have for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{15}$: $$\varphi(1)(n) = 1+n-1 = n?$$ This is the trivial automorphism however, which is in direct contradiction to the fact that $\varphi(1) = (1,0)$ isn't trivial.

Essentially what I'm asking for is an explanation on how one deduces that (in the context of the linked post): "if $\varphi(1)=(1,0)$, then
$P_2 \rtimes_{\varphi} N \cong D_{15}$ because _____, and if $\varphi(1)=(0,2)$, then $P_2 \rtimes_{\varphi} N \cong \mathbb{Z}_5 \times S_3$ because ___..."

Could someone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Groundwork

We are trying to understand semidirect products of the form $ℤ_{15} ⋊_φ ℤ_2$.
We rely on the following observations:

- Let $R$ be a ring and let $u$ be an element of $R^×$.
  The map
  $$
    λ_u
    \colon
    R \to R \,,
    \quad
    x \mapsto ux
  $$
  is an automorphism of the underlying additive group of $R$.
  We have thus a homomorphism of groups
  $$
    λ
    \colon
    R^× \to \operatorname{Aut}_ℤ(R) \,,
    \quad
    u \mapsto λ_u \,.
  $$
  This homomorphism is always injective because $u$ can be retrieved from $λ_u$ as $u = λ_u(1)$.
  If $R = ℤ_n$, then $λ$ is also surjectiv, and thus an isomorphism of groups $\operatorname{Aut}_ℤ(ℤ_n) ≅ ℤ_n^×$.
- Given two coprime integers $m$ and $n$, we have an isomorphism of rings (and thus in particular of abelian gorups) $ℤ_{mn} ≅ ℤ_m × ℤ_n$ given by $[k] \mapsto ([k], [k])$.
- For every two rings $R$ and $S$, we have $(R × S)^× = R^× × S^×$.
- Given any group $G$, homomorphism of groups from $ℤ_2$ is $G$ are uniquely determined by their image of the element $1$ of $ℤ_2$.
  This image can be any element of $G$ whose order divides $2$.
  (In other words, this element can either be the neutral element of $G$, or an element of order $2$.
  The neutral element corresponds to the trivial homomorphism from $ℤ_2$ to $G$.)

Let us fix a piece of notation:

- Let $R$ be a ring and let $u$ be an element of $R^×$ whose order divides $2$.
  Let $ψ_u$ be the resulting homomorphism of groups from $ℤ_2$ to $\operatorname{Aut}_ℤ(R)$ with $ψ_u(1) = λ_u$.
  We then abbreviate the resulting semidirect product $R ⋊_{ψ_u} ℤ_2$ as $R ⋊_u ℤ_2$.
  (Inside of the group $R ⋊_u ℤ_2$, the conjucation action of $ℤ_2$ on $R$ is thus given by multiplication with $u$.)

We will need one very explicit example of this general construction:

- For every positive integer $n$, we have $ℤ_n ⋊_{-1} ℤ_2 ≅ \mathrm{D}_n$.
  (We use here the standard description of the dihedral group $\mathrm{D}_n$ as a semidirect product of $ℤ_n$ by $ℤ_2$.)

We will also need the following observation:

- Let $R$ and $S$ be two rings.

  - Let $r$ be an element of $R^×$ whose order divides $2$.
    We then get the element $(r, 1)$ of $(R × S)^×$, whose order again divides $2$.
    The resulting action of $ℤ_2$ on $R × S$ does nothing on the second factor.
    (More explicitly, the element $1$ of $ℤ_2$ acts on the first factor by multiplication with $r$, and on the second factor by multiplication with $1$.)
    We get from this observation an isomorphism of groups
    $$
      (R × S) ⋊_{(r, 1)} ℤ_2
      ≅
      (R ⋊_R ℤ_2) × S \,.
    $$
  - Similarly, if $s$ is an element of $S^×$ whose order divides $2$, then
    $$
      (R × S) ⋊_{(1, s)} ℤ_2
      ≅
      R × (S ⋊_s ℤ_2) \,.
    $$

## Computation of elements

Let us examine the chain of isomorphisms
$$
  ℤ_{15}^×
  ≅
  (ℤ_3 × ℤ_5)^×
  =
  ℤ_3^× × ℤ_5^×
  ≅
  ℤ_2 × ℤ_4
$$
in more detail:

- The isomorphism $ℤ_{15} ≅ ℤ_3 × ℤ_5$ comes from the chinese reminder theorem because $3$ and $5$ are coprime.
  More explicitly, the map
  $$
    θ
    \colon
    ℤ_{15} \to ℤ_3 × ℤ_5 \,,
    \quad
    [n] \mapsto ([n], [n])
  $$
  is an isomorphism.
  We can also give an explicit formula for the inveres of $θ$:
  we have $θ^{-1}(1, 0) = 10 = -5$ and $θ^{-1}(0, 1) = 6$, and therefore
  $$
    θ^{-1}([m], [n]) = [-5m + 6n] \,.
  $$
- The groups $ℤ_3^×$ and $ℤ_5^×$ are cyclic, and generated by the elements $2$ and $2$ respectively.
  We can therefore choose the isomorphism $ℤ_3^× × ℤ_5^× ≅ ℤ_2 × ℤ_4$ so that an element $([k], [l])$ of $ℤ_2 × ℤ_4$ corresponds to the element $(2^k, 2^l)$ of $ℤ_3^× × ℤ_5^×$.

For an element $([k], [l])$ of $ℤ_2 × ℤ_4$ we therefore find that

- the resulting element of $ℤ_3^× × ℤ_5^×$ is given by $(2^k, 2^l)$;
- the resulting element of $ℤ_{15}^×$ is given by $[-5 ⋅ 2^k + 6 ⋅ 2^l]$.

We have now the following elements in the groups $ℤ_2 × ℤ_4$, $ℤ_3^× × ℤ_5^×$ and $ℤ_{15}^×$ whose order divides $2$.

| $ℤ_2 × ℤ_4 $ | $ℤ_3^× × ℤ_5^×$ | $ℤ_{15}^×$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $(0, 0)$ | $(1, 1)$ | $-5 + 6 = 1$ |
| $(0, 2)$ | $(1, 4) = ( 1, -1)$ | $-5 + 24 = 19 = 4$ |
| $(1, 0)$ | $(2, 1) = (-1, 1)$ | $-10 + 6 = -4$ |
| $(1, 2)$ | $(2, 4) = (-1, -1)$ | $-10 + 24 = 14 = -1$ |

For every element of $ℤ_2 × ℤ_4$, the corresponding automorphisms of $ℤ_{15}$ are simply given by multiplication with corresponding element of $ℤ_{15}^×$.
As an example, the automorphism of $ℤ_{15}$ corresponding to the element $(1, 0)$ of $ℤ_4 × ℤ_2$ is given by multiplication with $-4$.

## Computation of semidirect products

Let us now compute the resulting semidirect products.

- The element $(0, 0)$ of $ℤ_2 × ℤ_4$ corresponds to the element $1$ of $ℤ_{15}^×$.
  The resulting automorphism of $ℤ_{15}$ is simply the identity automorphism, and the resulting homomorphism from $ℤ_2$ to $\operatorname{Aut}(ℤ_{15})$ is the trivial homomorphism.
  And the semidirect product resulting from the trivial homomorphism is simpli the direct product.
  Therefore,
  $$
    ℤ_{15} ⋊_1 ℤ_2 ≅ ℤ_{15} × ℤ_2 ≅ ℤ_{30} \,.
  $$
- The element $(0, 2)$ of $ℤ_2 × ℤ_4$ corresponds to the element $4$ of $ℤ_{15}$.
  To compute the resulting semidirect product $ℤ_{15} ⋊_4 ℤ_2$, we employ once again the isomorphism $ℤ_{15} ≅ ℤ_3 × ℤ_5$.
  The corresponding element in $ℤ_3 × ℤ_5$ is given by $(1, -1)$.
  We have therefore an isomorphism of groups
  $$
    ℤ_{15} ⋊_4 ℤ_2
    ≅
    (ℤ_3 × ℤ_5) ⋊_{(1, -1)} ℤ_2
    ≅
    ℤ_3 × (ℤ_5⋊_{-1} ℤ_2)
    ≅
    ℤ_3 × \mathrm{D}_5 \,.
  $$
- For the element $(1, 0)$ of $ℤ_2 × ℤ_4$ we find similarly that
  $$
    ℤ_{15} ⋊_{-4} ℤ_2
    ≅
    (ℤ_3 × ℤ_5) ⋊_{(-1, 1)} ℤ_2
    ≅
    (ℤ_3 ⋊_{-1} ℤ_2) × ℤ_5
    ≅
    \mathrm{D}_3 × ℤ_5
    ≅
    \mathrm{S}_3 × ℤ_5 \,.
  $$
- For the element $(1, 2)$ of $ℤ_2 × ℤ_4$ the corresponding element of $ℤ_{15}^×$ is given by $-1$.
  We find that
  $$
    ℤ_{15} ⋊_{-1} ℤ_2 ≅ \mathrm{D}_{15} \,.
  $$

Answer (score 2):

The setting was  $G \cong \mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z \rtimes_{\varphi} \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, where $\varphi : \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z)$ is a group homomorphism.

**1. Find an explicit description of $\varphi$**

We have $$\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z) \cong (\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z)^\times \cong (\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^\times = (\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)^\times \times (\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^\times \cong  \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z,$$
such that we may (for the moment) think of $\varphi$ as a map $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \to\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$

Clearly, $\varphi$ is determined by the image $\varphi(1)$.
Let us consider the example $\varphi(1) =(0,2) \in\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$.
To get the image $\varphi(1)\in \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z)$ in the original setting, we need to trace back the element $(0,2)\in\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ in the above chain of isomorphisms.

**First step**: $(\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)^\times \times (\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^\times \cong  \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$.

In $(0,2)\in\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$, the component $0$ is the neutral element in $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and $2$ is the unique element of order $2$ in $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$. Therefore, the preimage of the first component $0$ is the neutral element in $(\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)^\times$, which is $1$, and the preimage of the second component $1$ in $(\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^\times$ is $-1$, which has order $2$. Together, the sought after preimage is $(1,-1)$.

**Second step**
$(\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z)^\times \cong (\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)^\times \times (\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z)^\times$

This is based on the Chinese remainder theorem $\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z \cong \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$. For the preimage of $(1,-1)$ we need an integer having remainder $1$ mod $3$ and remainder $-1$ mod $5$. There is an algorithm for this computation (based on the Euclidean algorithm), but in this small case we simply check a few numbers and find
the preimage $4\in 15 \mathbb Z/\mathbb Z$.

**Third step** $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z) \cong (\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z)^\times$

This is easy. The concrete isomorphism (in the direction $\leftarrow$) is $a + \mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z \mapsto (x \mapsto ax)$. In our case, we get $x \mapsto 4x$

**Fourth step**
We have found $\varphi(1) = (x \mapsto 4x)$. What is $\varphi(a)$ for general $a\in\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.
In this case, this is very easy, as the only other element of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is the neutral element $0$. Of cource, $\varphi(0) = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z}$.

For general $a\in\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ we may combine this as as
$$\varphi(a) = (x \mapsto 4^a x).$$

(*Remark*. This would also work for larger cyclic groups instead of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ using $a = 1 + \ldots + 1$ and the homomorphism property of $\varphi$.)

**2. Determine the multiplication rule in the semidirect product**

The general multiplication rule in the outer semidirect product $N \rtimes_{\varphi} U$ is
$$(n_1, u_1) \cdot (n_2, u_2) = (n_1\cdot \varphi(h_1)(n_2), h_1 \cdot h_2)$$

For elements $(a_1,b_1), (a_2,b_2)\in \mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and $\varphi$ as above we get
$$(a_1,b_1) \cdot (a_2,b_2) = (a_1 + 4^{b_1} a_2,\, b_1 + b_2)$$

If you understand the above, you should be able to find the explicit multiplication rule also in the remaining cases.

**3. Determine the group**

We want to find out to which of the candidates $D_{15}$, $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z\times S_3$ and $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\times D_5$ our group $\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z\rtimes \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic.

In general, checking two groups for isomorphism can be pretty hard.
But in our case, counting the elements of order $2$ should be sufficient to distinguish the groups.

We count the elements of $(a,b)\in\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z\rtimes \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ of order $2$. We consider the equation $(a,b)\cdot (a,b) = (0,0)$. The second component is $2b = 0$, which is always true. The first component is $a(1 + 4^b) = 0$. For $b = 0$ this reduces to $2a = 0$ with the only solution $a = 0$. For $b = 1$ we get $5a = 0$ with five solutions $a\in\{0,3,6,9,12\}$ possible. Discarding the neutral element $(0,0)$, we have found the following five elements of order 2:
$$\{(0,1), (3,1), (6,1), (9,1), (12,1)\}$$

Now you can count the elements of order $2$ in $D_{15}$, $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z\times S_3$ and $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\times D_5$ to find out which one the considered semidirect product ist. (BTW, this also shows that the 3 candidate groups are pairwise non-isomorphic, as their number of elements of order $2$ differs.)

Answer (score 1):

My answer is shorter.

If I understand you correctly, first we need to figure out what the automorphisms of the group $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ look like.

Let $A=\langle5\rangle$, $B=\langle3\rangle$.  We have $\mathbb{Z}_{15}=A\oplus B$ and $|A|=3$, $|B|=5$.
Since $A$ and $B$ have coprime orders and $\operatorname{Aut}(A)\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$, $\operatorname{Aut}(B)\cong\mathbb{Z}_4$, it follows that
$$
\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{15})
\cong\operatorname{Aut}(A)\times\operatorname{Aut}(B)
\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4.
$$

Therefore, it is natural to assume that
the automorphism $\alpha=(1,0)$ acts as follows
$\alpha(a)=-a$ for all $a\in A$ and $\alpha(b)=b$ for all $b\in B$ or
$$
\alpha(5q)=-5q,\ \alpha(3p)=3p,\ q=1,2;\ p=1,2,3,4.
$$
It can be given by a single formula $\alpha(1)=11$ (Check).

This means that $\mathbb{Z}_{15}\rtimes_{\varphi_1} K\cong D_3\times \mathbb{Z}_5$, where
$\varphi_1(t)=\alpha$ (we assume that $|K|=2$ and $K=\langle t\rangle$).

Similarly $\beta=(0,2)$ acts as follows
$\beta(a)=a$ for all $a\in A$ and $\beta(b)=-b$ for all $b\in B$ or
$$
\beta(5q)=5q,\ \beta(3p)=-3p,\ q=1,2;\ p=1,2,3,4;
$$
or $\beta(1)=4$ (Check).

If $\varphi_2(t)=\beta$, then $\mathbb{Z}_{15}\rtimes_{\varphi_2} K\cong \mathbb{Z}_3\times D_5$.

And the last
$\gamma=(1,2)$ acts as follows
$\gamma(a)=-a$ for all $a\in A$ and $\gamma(b)=-b$ for all $b\in B$
or $\gamma(1)=-1$.

If $\varphi_3(t)=\gamma$, then $\mathbb{Z}_{15}\rtimes_{\varphi_3} K\cong D_{15}$.