# all subgroups of order of the product of distinct primes

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a group of order of pqrs (p < q < r < s, distint primes).
Does exist a subgroup H of order pq, pr, ps, qr, qs, pqr, ...?? 
I'm struggle with this problem. Any help please. Thank you.

Comment: Is that all the information of the Group? Lagrange's theorem can be useful, it unfortunately does not guarantee that there namely exists a subgroup of that order  $d, d|pqrs$.

Comment: I wonder what is known about the simpler case $pqr$. I have found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/314733/589