# Finding subgroup of order $30$ from $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

For what value of $n$, guarantee $S_n$ has a subgroup of order $30$

1. 5
2. 6
3. 7
4. 8

Its very clear that from the given option there is no $n$ for which $S_n$ contain any element of order $30$. Here I stuck to think how can I get the subgroup . Please help me

Comment: How is that clear? What about $S_3\times C_5$ within $S_8$?

Comment: If a€Sn and o(a) =30 then either a is a 30 cycle which is not possible or composition of disjont 5cycle, 3cycle and 2 cycle. Then Sn have to contain atleast (5+3+2) =10 simbol.

Comment: The 2-cycle and 3-cycle do not need to be disjoint, as $S_3$ illustrates.

Comment: I cannot understand. If they not disjont then how can be the order 30. Can you please give me an example or explain

Comment: You are talking past each other. That example has no element of order $30$, but it is a subgroup of order $30$.

Comment: Yes. I search for the subgroup. But cant understand how can I get that

Comment: @runway has told you how to get one, when $n=8$.

Comment: Actually I cannot understand. Please explain

Comment: Do you know what $S_3$ is? Do you know what $C_5$ is? Do you know what $S_3\times C_5$ means? Can you find a subgroup of $S_8$ isomorphic to $S_3$? Can you find a subgroup of $S_8$ isomorphic to $C_5$? Can you find subgroups of $S_8$, one of them isomorphic to $S_3$, the other isomorphic to $C_5$, and having no element in common, other than the identity?

Comment: @DebprasadKundu, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups#:~:text=The%20order%20of%20a%20direct,the%20cartesian%20product%20of%20sets. See second line in elementary properties section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every group of order $30$ has an element of order $15$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/314582/589)). This rules out options 1,2,3.

Option 4, which is $n=8$, works: take $H=AB$ where $A=\langle (12),(123) \rangle \cong S_3$ and $B=\langle (45678) \rangle \cong C_5$. Note that $A$ and $B$ commute elementwise.